# positive and negative button on react native android permission rational alert

Tags: android, android-permissions, react-native

I am new to react native and need to implement react native android permissions.

There is an option to pass `title` and `message` for the `rational alert` in `AndroidPermissions` but I am unable to find a way to add `Positive` and `Negative` button on the rational alert.

This looks unfamiliar to me as in android generally we have at least one "OK" button on every dialog/Alert.

Same has been asked on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13920 but closed without any solution.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to create your own dialog? Why don't you use the default by adding your permissions to your android manifest file? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a bit too late for an answer but this may help someone in the future.

Use buttonNeutral, buttonNegative and buttonPositive in the rationale object like below

```
const locationPermissionRationale = {
title: "Location Access",
message: 'Need for detect your location to select location nearby you easily'
// how to create Positive and Negative alert dialog button here ?
buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
buttonNegative:"Cancel",
buttonPositive: "OK"
```

}

The solution above is from the issue referenced here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13920

Comment: how can i do click work on the above buttons,buttonNeutral,  buttonNegative,buttonPositive @willynwai